# How to tell whether a given target is a library or executable?

Tags: cmake

The built-in function `install(TARGETS ...)` installs library targets to another location than executable targets. I want to do something similar. Given a list of target names, I want to add all library targets among them to a list variable and all runtime targets to another variable.

I couldn't found a list of CMake's default target properties, but I guess `add_library()` and `add_executable()` add a property that can be used for this kind of distinction.

How to tell whether a given target is a library or executable (or even something else)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to documentation, [TYPE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/TYPE.html) property can be used for distinguish standard CMake target types:

> It will be one of STATIC_LIBRARY, MODULE_LIBRARY, SHARED_LIBRARY, EXECUTABLE or one of the internal target types.

Example:

```
get_target_property(target_type <target> TYPE)
if (target_type STREQUAL "EXECUTABLE")
  # Process executable target
endif ()
```