# CMake: Check if a target is a SHARED library inside a generator expression

Tags: cmake

All in the title, I want to be able to check if a TARGET `Foo` is a shared library (or a static lib) so I need to add it in a .csproj generated file (using a generator expression).

Something like this:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
file(GENERATE
  OUTPUT .../$<CONFIG>/foo.csproj
  INPUT foo.csproj.in)
...
```

foo.csproj.in:

```
...
<Content Include="$<TARGET_FILE:Bar>$<$<BOOL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Foo:BUILD_SHARED_LIBS>>:;$<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Foo>>">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/@RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER@/native/%(Filename)%(Extension)</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
...
```

### Expected output

- if `Foo` is a shared lib (e.g. `option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries (.so or .dyld)." ON)`)
  I want:

foo.csproj

```
...
<Content Include="build/lib/Bar.so;build/lib/Foo.so">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native/%(Filename)%(Extension)</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
...
```

- if `Foo` is a static lib (e.g. `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`)
  I want:

foo.csproj

```
...
<Content Include="build/lib/Bar.dll">
      <PackagePath>runtimes/win-x64/native/%(Filename)%(Extension)</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
...
```

Comment: You could try to examine `TYPE` property of the target and compare it with `SHARED_LIBRARY` or `STATIC_LIBRARY`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908066/3440745

Answer (score 2):

After few tests (and as @Tsyvarev spot it):

```
$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Foo,TYPE>,SHARED_LIBRARY>:;$<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Foo>>
```

side note: must use `SHARED_LIBRARY` (without quotes) and **NOT** `"SHARED_LIBRARY"`

src:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/TYPE.html